# How to properly quote / escape this INSERT statement in Zend 1 Framework

Tags: mysqli, zend-framework, php-7.4

I am stuck with an ancient Zend 1 project, which we gradually want to fade into Symfony.

My colleague created an repository with the following code:

```php
    public function insert(Address $address): int
    {
        $sql = <<<SQL
            insert into contract_request.applicant_address 
                (applicant_uuid, street, street_number, postcode, city)
                VALUES
                    (
                     {$address->getApplicantUuid()},
                     '{$address->getStreet()}',
                     {$address->getStreetNumber()},
                     '{$address->getPostcode()}',
                     '{$address->getCity()}'
                    )        
        SQL;
        $stmt = new Zend_Db_Statement_Mysqli($this->db, $sql);
        $stmt->execute();

        $addressId = $this->db->lastInsertId();

        return (int) $addressId;
    }
```

Which works nicely as long as no text with an apostrophe is inserted e.g. `'t Hertogenbosch` which can happen.
So how can I properly escape critical strings before inserting them into the db with this construct? Changing the single quote signs to double doesn't help.

I found similar questions only for select queries.

Comment: all this data should go into execute()

Comment: What exactly do you mean by this?

Comment: https://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.db.statement.html

Comment: Converting it to named parameters helped!

Comment: It's exactly the same as with select queries, no reason to think otherwise. Leaving this closed as duplicate due to this.